# how to delete specific data from text file and then update it

Tags: export, import, text, filtering

I have a large text file. I read data from text file one at a time and check whether data agree with my condition. If not I want to delete that data in text file and update it.

For example say my data text file is:
100
201
302
455

Suppose I want to delete second one. After deletion I want new text file to be look like
100
302
455 
(without any gap between 100 and 302). Since my text file is large around 100MB, I want to read data one by one rather than loading all at once. Thanks

Comment: Just use sed and be done with it :)  something like `sed --in-place '/201/d' file.txt`

Comment: @Nasser Surely dedicated text utilities are a better approach for simple replacements.  I have to assume that the condition here is nontrivial and requires or at least benefits from *Mathematica* processing.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard yes ofcourse, I understand that. I was just giving an answer for the specific example (I also put a smiley, there, just in case :)

Comment: @Nasser From your response I think I failed to communicate what I intended.  Let me try again:  Using an external text processing utility is a *great idea* and should be used *whenever possible* as it will deliver superior performance in nearly all cases.

Answer (score 7):

100MB is small compared to today's RAM sizes.  Why not load it all at once?  Then it's just a matter of using `DeleteCases` and exporting the file.

Otherwise I don't believe *Mathematica* is natively equipped to modify a file piece by piece in that fashion so you'll need to export to a second file.  As an example I'll filter a list of natural numbers to keep only the primes.  (It would be a trivial use of [`Not`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Not.html) to drop the primes.)

First generate the starting data:

```
Export["firstfile.txt", Range@100, "Table"];
```

Open the input and output streams:

```
in = OpenRead["firstfile.txt"];
out = OpenWrite["secondfile.txt"];
```

Read, filter, and export:

```
Module[{x},
 While[x =!= EndOfFile,
  x = Read[in];
  If[PrimeQ@x, Write[out, x]]
 ]
]
```

Close the streams:

```
Scan[Close, {in, out}]
```

The result:

```
FilePrint["secondfile.txt"]
```

> ```
> 2
> 3
> 5
> 7
> 11
> 13
> ...
> ```

Note:  practically I would include `in` and `out` in my `Module` but here it made it harder to comment the code as I wanted.

Comment: thank you for the answer. It really helped me. Thank you again for the help.

Comment: @Vajira You're welcome.  If you find the answer fully satisfactory please consider [Accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/158428) it.